# Gradle Project Not Naming Archives Properly Under Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-plugins

I have a number of Gradle builds that work very well from the command line, from buildship, etc.

However now I am porting them to a Jenkins system. And it is producing some very strange results. I'm pretty much a total newbie to Jenkins, so this may have an easy answer. So far I haven't found it.

I am using the [Gradle Plugin for Jenkins, v.1.24](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) to configure my build in Jenkins. However, Jenkins (at least as I have it configured) organizes its build structure as `{jenkins root}/data/jobs/{project_name}/workspace`. When code is checked out of source control it is deposited in that directory, not in a directory named `{project_name}`.

Gradle seems to assume that the directory in which it is running names the project, and when I'm running outside of Jenkins this assumption is true. The name of the project that Gradle sees is the name of the project that was checked out from source control. Project.name is a gettable but not a settable property of a gradle Project. So in the Jenkins case, the archives that gradle builds are named `workspace*` rather than `{project_name}*`. It is also named `workspace` in the repositories it publishes into. I must be missing something very obvious but for the life of me I cannot figure out what it is.

Has anyone grappled with this?

**UPDATE** - It appears that the problem is that the people who designed my Jenkins instance knew nothing about Gradle. The `{jenkins root}/data/jobs/{project_name}/workspace` layout that I described above is not required by Jenkins, but apparently was felt to be useful for some reason in some other, non-Gradle context.  So the question becomes, where is the project layout set up in the Jenkins configuration - OR - can Gradle be modified somehow to assume a different project layout/naming strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → <kbd>***Advanced...***</kbd> (the one right at the top) → *Workspace Root Directory*: `${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}`.

The inline help:

> Specify where Jenkins would store job workspaces on the master node. (It has no effect on builds run on slaves.) This value can include the following variables.
>
> - `${JENKINS_HOME}` — Jenkins home directory.
> - `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}` — Root directory of a job for which the default workspace is allocated.
> - `${ITEM_FULL_NAME}` — '/'-separated job name, like "foo/bar".
>
> Changing this value allows you to put workspaces on SSD, SCSI, or even ram disks. Default value is `${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace`.

#### `.../jenkins/config.xml`

```
...
<workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}</workspaceDir>
...
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is very useful.  This is clearly the place to make these changes.  But can you tell me what config file this is stored in?  I have another not-currently-runnable instance with a different setup.  I'd like to see what these values are in that instance.

Answer (score 0):

> Gradle seems to assume that the directory in which it is running names the project

Yes this is gradle's default behavior, but can be easily overridden. If it is just the output artifact name you're concerned about, override the jar name with:

```
jar{
    baseName 'actualProjectName'
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to have to do this on every single project, and artifact, etc.  And if I do that, I want to do it in one place per project maximum so that I am not surprised by jar names, war names, rpm names, repository directory names, etc.  Building something in Jenkins should not be different from building it at the command line.